# instalar angular cli en docker produce node: Permission denied

Tags: nodejs, angularjs, docker, npm, angular-cli

Tengo un problema al instalar angular-cli en un docker.

Estoy ejecutando el comando

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

y me muestra el error adjunto

> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/bin/ng ->
>   /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
>
> -> node-sass@4.5.3 install /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
>   -> node scripts/install.js
>
> sh: 1: node: Permission denied
>
> -> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.6.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
>   -> node lib/post_install.js
>
> sh: 1: node: Permission denied npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2
>   (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"}) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL
>   DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3
>   (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass): npm WARN optional
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.5.3 install: `node
>   scripts/install.js` npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   spawn ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! file sh npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno ENOENT npm
>   ERR! syscall spawn npm ERR! uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall:
>   `node lib/post_install.js` npm ERR! spawn ENOENT npm ERR!  npm ERR!
>   Failed at the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script. npm
>   ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2017-10-02T04_39_45_327Z-debug.log

Comment: Prueba con sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
npm config set unsafe-perm true
```

Valor predeterminado: **false** si se ejecuta como **root**, **true** de lo contrario, Tipo: **Boolean** Se establece en **true** para suprimir la conmutación UID/GID al ejecutar secuencias de comandos de paquete. Si se establece explícitamente en **false**, se producirá un error al instalar como un usuario no **root**.

consulte el https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm

**sh: 1: node: Permiso denegado**

Ejemplo:

problema:

```
> node install.js

sh: 1: node: Permission denied
```

Solución:

```
npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
sudo npm install -g sm
```

`unsafe-perm` es inseguro aunque no debe necesitar **sudo** o **perms** inseguros para hacer nada con node/npm.

Comment: SoftMolina, esta respuesta ha sido reportada por su extensión y contenido. Debes intentar que las respuestas sean autocontenidas y autoexplicativas. Si es posible completa tu respuesta con  una explicación de que hace este comando y como soluciona el problema concreto del OP, posibles efectos de usarlo, enlace a la documentación, etc. Tal y como esta se parece mas a un comentario y es posible que sea eliminada. Un saludo.

Comment: agradezco mucho tu ayuda te comento que ya logre resolver el problema me complace decirte que con los comandos  npm config set user 0
npm config set unsafe-perm true
sudo npm install -g sm  los logre resolver

Answer (score 1):

Ejecutalo siendo **root**:

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`